# Update FragmentPagerAdapter pageTitle dynamically

Tags: android

So I have a class

```
public class TabPagerAdapter extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i("debug", "notifyDataSetChanged tabpager");
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Log.i("debug", "getPageTitle tabpager");
        // ...
    }
}
```

And here is the usage of the adapter:

```
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pagerAdapter = new TabPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
```

Now when I want to update the title of the fragments dynamically (so `getPageTitle()` should be called again) I tried this `pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`, which was marked as an answer in similiar questions. But nothing happens here. The first logging is printed, getPageTitle is not called again.

I tried many other things, which where advised in other answers, like:

- `mViewPager.destroyDrawingCache();`
- Overwriting `FragmentPagerAdapter::getItemPosition`

  @Override
  public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
      return POSITION_NONE;
  }

but nothing worked for me.

Any idea?

Comment: Why the downvote? Please add a comment if you're downvoting my question and add some constructive feedback...

Answer (score 0):

I have used this one and it worked well for me :

```
 mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // getActionBar().setTitle("title from your list");
                }
            });
```

Thanks